# Visual Studio Code no inicia el env de python que quiero

Tags: python, django, vscode, powershell, virtualenv

Sería mi primer solicitud de ayuda por acá, una página que me ha ayudado tanto.

**Problema**: con Visual Studio Code y su última versión me trajo este problema.

Supuestamente estoy en el env (django2) donde tengo instalado django, pero no se activa el env al hacer el típico `"conda activate django2"` que incluso VSC hace automáticamente, después de hacer lo anterior hago un `pip list` y no aparece el django que tengo instalado, por lo tanto es como si NO estuviese dentro del env (django2).

**Les dejo la captura de mi VSC:**
[[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]]

Este problema comenzó desde que se instaló la última actualización de Visual Studio Code.

¡Saludos y buena vibra!
***cabe comentar que puedo entrar sin problemas al env python (django2) desde CMD de Windows.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: ¬¬ es clarisimo...

Comment: ¿Qué extensiones python estás usando? Asegúrate de que tienes las extensiones apropiadas (_MagicPython_ ya no es necesaria). Comprueba la configuración `"python.terminal.activateEnvironment": true` (opcionalmente también `python.terminal.activateEnvInCurrentTerminal`)

Comment: si has solucionado tu problema responde a tu propia pregunta **NO** en tu pregunta, sino elaborando una respuesta y publicándola en la sección de respuestas

Answer (score 1):

Probé lo de **@ChemaCortes** y el `"python.terminal.activateEnvironment":` si estaba en  **true** y `python.terminal.activateEnvInCurrentTerminal` estaba desactivado y ya lo activé, reinicie y se activó el env automáticamente: `conda activate django2` pero igual se quedó así en el **powershell**:

```
. : No se puede cargar el archivo C:\Users\usuarioxxxxxx\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\profile.ps1 porque la ejecución de scripts está deshabilitada en este sistema. Para obtener más información, vea el tema about_Execution_Policies en http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
En línea: 1 Carácter: 3
+ . 'C:\Users\usuarioxxxxx\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\profile.ps1'
+   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess

PS C:\CursoDjango\proyectodjango> conda activate django2

PS C:\CursoDjango\proyectodjango>
```

También probé lo de **@Rigo** y en efecto, tampoco estaba el directorio `.vscode` y lo cree editando el json:

```
{
    "python.pythonPath": "C:\\Miniconda3\\envs\\django2\\python.exe",
    "python.terminal.activateEnvInCurrentTerminal": true
}
```

Después de hacer esto y reiniciar VSC, cargó y ejecutó en poweshell el comando `PS C:\CursoDjango\proyectodjango> conda activate django2` pero tampoco entró al entorno virtual (django2).

#### La solución alternativa:

Esto no pasaba antes de la última actualización, lo que hice fue agregar un **Command prompt** y ahí se ejecutó de inmediato el env (django2) sin problemas.

```
(base) C:\CursoDjango\proyectodjango>conda activate django2

(django2) C:\CursoDjango\proyectodjango>
```

Por lo tanto, se puede dar como **solucionado el problema**, igual, si hay alguna otra sugerencia para que me funcione el Poweshell como debería será bienvenida.

Gracias a quienes me respondieron y perdón a los moderadores, aún soy nuevo en la plataforma **stackoverflow** ¡saludos y buena vibraaaa!

Answer (score 0):

Dentro del directorio de tu proyecto hay un directorio oculto: .vscode, dentro de este hay un archivo JSON en el cual debe estar el path de venv que estés ocupando, podes revisar ese archivo y ver si es el correcto, o no está configurado. La clave de este debe ser: "python.pythonPath"